# Surface area of elliptic paraboloid

Tags: surface-integrals

I'm trying to write the surface area of the part of the paraboloid:
$$z=(1/2)x^2+(1/2)y^2$$ where $$z\leq a^2/2$$
as double integrals
in Cartesian and Cylindrical coordinates.

For Cartesian coordinates do I need to parameterise?

Comment: open elliptic paraboloid (z>0)?

Comment: https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#q=z%3D1%2F2x%5E2%2B1%2F2+y%5E2

Comment: https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#q=z%3D1%2F2x%5E2%2B1%2F2+y%5E2

Comment: $z=1/2x^2+1/2y^2$ is the equation of the rotation axis paraboloid with the z axis.

Comment: would the inner limits just be the circle mapped at the bottom of the paraboloid in terms of x and the outer limits equal to the radius of that base circle?

Comment: See [surface of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula).

Comment: need in terms of double integrals.

Comment: @WillJagy Could you parameterise the cylindrical coordinates as x=sqr root 2z    y= sqr root 2z   and z=z?